# Match multiple strings using re.search within an if condition

Tags: regex, python-2.7, conditional-statements

I am writing a program to create a list from a spreadsheet based on a `position` value in another cell. So my code looks like

```
for j in xrange(1,13):
    for sheet in wb.sheets():
        for i in xrange(1,12*15):
            team=sheet.cell(i,0)
            position=sheet.cell(i,2)
            games=sheet.cell(i,23)
            if re.match(owner[j], str(team.value)) and (not re.findall('Defense' or 'K,' or 'KFG' or 'KKO', str(position.value))):
                try:
                    list.append(int(games.value))
                except ValueError:
                    list.append(0)
            else:
                pass
    print list
    list=[]
```

So the goal of this is to append to a list when a row matches `owner` in the first column, and not `Defense` `K,` `KFG` `KKO` in the position column.

Unfortunately, the values for `K`, `KFG` and `KKO` all show
up in my lists, but the `Defense` values properly do not. How can I
ensure the other filtering criteria are met?

As a side note, these positions are in amongst other bits of text so
the `search()` is used here instead of `match()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Defense" is a 'truthy' value, so the result of:

```
'Defense' or 'K,' or 'KFG' or 'KKO'
```

is `'Defense'`.

Therefore, the condition you have is no different from:

```
re.match(owner[j], str(team.value)) and (not re.findall('Defense', str(position.value)))
```

If you want alternatives in a regex, use `|` in the pattern:

```
re.match(owner[j], str(team.value)) and (not re.findall('Defense|K,|KFG|KKO', str(position.value)))
```